# Download and render HTML in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I want to download HTML files from some source and render it in a specific component of my angular app (with its CSS and Js). I do not want solutions like `<iframe></iframe>` because the HTML file will not be hosted. Also, I tried `[innerHTML]` but this can not link HTML file to CSS and Js files.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: use object tag? although iframe is better in this case.

Comment: iframe needs link, but the HTML wont be hosted. I have to download it via httpClient and after this render it in my front app.